# Can Python open files using open() when files are in the same folder?

Tags: python, file

I am following a tutorial on reading and writing to files and I keep getting this error when attempting to read a txt file called a.txt:

*File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Learning\Python\Reading and Writing to Files\file-demo.py", line 3, in 

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a.txt'*

Both my text file and my Python file are in the folder Reading and Writing to Files so I am confused as to why I get this error.

Here is my code:

```
# File Objects 

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:
   f_contents = f.read()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You probably don't have the file in the current working directory. Try importing `os` and printing `os.getcwd()` to show where python is looking for files.

Comment: Yes relative paths are supported with `open`, double check that the `cwd` is what you think it is. You can double check this with `os.getcwd`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a code editor like VS Code, then make sure that the `.txt` file is in the main folder opened in your code editor else it won't work.

But it will still work if you run the `.py` file from the File Explorer.

Comment: Thanks Sumit! I am indeed using VS Code and I did not have the .txt file in the main folder. This solved my issue. Best,

Answer (score 0):

I think even though the script and file are in the same folder, open() function can't know it. So you have to specify where the file is located in order to use open() function. First of all, if you are going to work with files, folders, directories or location etc, 'os' (stands for: operating system) module is useful.

```
import os
```

you can get your folder location  where your script is located,using 'getcwd' function and save it into a string.

```
dir = os.getcwd()
```

Now you can use this string as parameter for open() function